# How to change Property out of DevicePicker.DeviceSelected Event in Command

Tags: mvvm, properties, binding, uwp, command

I have a ConnectButton binded to a Command. In his Command Im calling the DevicePicker and set the DeviceSelected Event to a method.

```
private void connectButtonCommand()
    {
        DevicePicker myDevicePicker = new DevicePicker();
        myDevicePicker.Show(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 200));
        //myDevicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false));
        myDevicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));
        myDevicePicker.DeviceSelected += MyDevicePicker_DeviceSelected;


    }
```

and the Method

```
private async void MyDevicePicker_DeviceSelected(DevicePicker sender, DeviceSelectedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deviceInfo = args.SelectedDevice as DeviceInformation;
        Device = deviceInfo;

        BluetoothController = new BluetoothController.BluetoothController();

        var list = await BluetoothController.FindPairedDevicesAsync();

        RefcommDevice = list.First(x => x.Id.Contains(Device.Id));

        List<DeviceInformation> deviceList = new List<DeviceInformation>();

        deviceList = list.ToList();

        Device = deviceList[0];

        connected = await BluetoothController.ConnectAsync(RefcommDevice);

        isConnected = connected;

        IsConnectedEvent += new IsConnectedEentHandler(Device_IsConnected);

        if (IsConnected)
        {
            if(IsConnectedEvent != null)
                IsConnectedEvent();
        }



        paired = true;

    }
```

The Device_IsConnected method should set some properties like this:

```
    private void Device_IsConnected()
    {
            ConnectButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            OnButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            OffButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ReadDatafButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
```

Thi is not working. I get the following error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8001010E): Eine Schnittstelle, die für einen anderen Thread marshalled war, wurde von der Anwendung aufgerufen. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
   at System.StubHelpers.EventArgsMarshaler.CreateNativePCEventArgsInstance(String name)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.PropertyChangedEventArgsMarshaler.ConvertToNative(PropertyChangedEventArgs managedArgs)
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at ArduinoDistance.ViewModels.BaseViewModel.SetProperty[T](T& Storage, T Value, String PropertyName)
   at ArduinoDistance.ViewModels.StartPageViewModel.set_ConnectButtonVisibility(Visibility value)
   at ArduinoDistance.ViewModels.StartPageViewModel.Device_IsConnected()

Is there a simple way to solve this? I solved it know by set in connectButtonCommand() a while(!IsConnected) and make there my UI changes. But I think thi is ot the best way.

**EDIT**
Solved the Problem by Using:

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => 
        testMethod());
```

Thanks

Agredo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the problem is the thread on which the call occurs: the app cannot manipulate UI elements from non-UI threads. In this case the problem is that you invoke the `Device_IsConnected`  method which contains UI relative code in the non-UI thread.

To fix this, move the calls to those methods to the UI thread by calling `Dispatcher.RunAsync`. For example:

```
await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
   // Your UI update code goes here!
   Device_IsConnected();
});
```

Details please reference [`CoreDispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher).

Comment: This is not Working.  Window.Current == null Maybe because i am in my ViewModel?

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped a lot!